# event Press outside view react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I want to close picker when I press outside? Please help

[image]

Comment: which library u are using

Comment: I don't use library, I use flat list to render item.

Comment: Show us the code

Answer (score 0):

1.First solution

```
<View >
    <TouchOpacity opPress={closePopup}>
        <View>{Popup of u here}</View>
    </TouchOpacity>
</View>
```

2. Using Overlay of react-native-elements libary

Comment: thanks you, but I want to close picker when I press outside, do you know event of view?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer without looking at what your code is but you could try something like this:

```
closePopup = _ => {
  this.setState(previousState => ({ isFlatListVisible: false }));
}

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.closePopup}>
  {isFlatListVisible && <FlatList />}
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```